# combine files same prefix text files into one

Tags: bash

I am trying to use `bash` to merge/combine all text files in a directory with the same prefix into one text file. Thank you :).

**directory**

```
111.txt
aaa
aaa
222_1.txt
bbb
222_2.txt
ccc
ccc
333_1.txt
aaa
333_2.txt
ccc
ccc
333_3.txt
bbb
```

**desired**

```
111.txt
aaa
aaa
222.txt
bbb
ccc
ccc
333.txt
aaa
ccc
ccc
bbb
```

**bash**

```
for file in `ls`|cut -d"_" -f1 ; do
  cat ${file}_* > ${file}
done
```

Comment: What is the prefix of `333._3.txt`? Is the content of `333.txt_1` and `333.txt_2` listed twice in the input?

Comment: I have fixed the typo's in the post, sorry... the prefix is the `333` before the `_`. Thank you :).

Answer (score 6):

This is a good use of an associative array as a set. Iterate over the file names, trimming the trailing `_*` from each name before adding it to the associative array. Then you can iterate over the array's keys, treating each one as a filename prefix.

```
# IMPORTANT: Assumes there are no suffix-less file names that contain a _
declare -A prefixes
for f in *; do
    prefixes[${f%_*}]=
done

for f in "${!prefixes[@]}"; do
    [ -f "$f".txt ] && continue  # 111.txt doesn't need anything done
    cat "$f"_* > "$f".txt
done
```

Comment: This seems to work except for the `111.txt` line, which does not contain a `_`.... that file gets emptied and all others with the `_` are combined. Thank you :).

Comment: Ah, that was a casualty of adding `_` to the `cat` command, which was necessary for those files. Should be fixable, though.

Answer (score 1):

build a test environment just as you did

```
mkdir -p tmp/test
cd !$
touch {111,222,333}.{txt,_2.txt,_3.txt}
cat > 111.txt
aaa
aaa
```

and so on

then you know how to increment filnames :

```
for i in $( seq 1 3 ) ; do echo $i*  ; done                                                                                                                
111._2.txt 111._3.txt 111.txt
222._2.txt 222._3.txt 222.txt
333._2.txt 333._3.txt 333.txt
```

*so you make your resulting files and here is the answer of mechanism to your needs :*

```
for i in $( seq 1 9 ) ; do  cat $i* >> new.$i.txt  ; done
```

and finaly

```
ls -l new.[1-3]*
-rw-r--r-- 1 francois francois 34 Aug  4 14:04 new.1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 francois francois 34 Aug  4 14:04 new.2.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 francois francois 34 Aug  4 14:04 new.3.txt
```

all 3* contents are in new.".txt for example here.
you only have to set the desired file destination to add in the content & if needed but not set in initial question a sorting of datas by alphabetic order or numerical... etc